# selectively lighting objects in a scene

Tags: materials

Below is a given scene with three consecutively placed cubes, and a simple sunlamp with green hue for emission facing perpendicular to the cube's face. The thing I want to do is that, I want make the sunlamp treat the first cube as if it were transparent i.e. the light from the sunlamp should go straight through the first cube and hit the second cube, and have also provided the screenshot of the node setup of the sunlamp:
[image]

I've change the first cube's pass index to 1 and the rest have 0 so, I thought this would work, but the logic failed. Plus it's necessary to have the materials of the cubes separate. Please tell me how to do this with a bit of node trickery?

Comment: can you cheat and use the compositor and just render it multiple times hiding the relevant bits? Also, can you give an example "why", we may have a better way of achieving the effect?

Comment: Well, I am not much familiar with the compositor, but someone in reddit said that this would be done in the compositor if you want to combine different thing. As for the second remark, I don't know if any other way, if there is, _is_ a better way. If I could somehow could achieve this, then tweaking the lighting and seeing one superimposed effect would be better... is what I think.